# How can i select where i install the ubuntu aplications?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I want to download programs like Cmap tools or Geany to a removable drive, but I don't now how.

Comment: Do you want to install them on usb drive or just want to get the .deb files on the drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want that you need to install and compile the source version of that package and during compilation provide an installation path to the removable drive.

- [Geany building from source](http://www.geany.org/manual/index.html#installation).
- Cmap tools is not open source so it totally depends on what is inside the .BIN file you get when you download it. If installing it asks for an installation path you can provide it but it probably will extract itself to the default locations. If so it will not be possible to put onto a removable drive.

For Ubuntu to work with that software that removable drive needs to be EXT and can not be NTFS.

I would suggest to forget this idea. It is a lot of work and you will also have to manually update this software when there is a new version or if there are bugfixes.

Answer (score 0):

The nature of `.deb` packages doesn't allow you to change the install location of programs. The whole philosophy of the Unix-like systems is based on the strict directory settlement: we have separate place for configs (`/etc/`), for libraries (`/var/lib`), etc.

If you want to carry a program, it must to be compiled as static at least, and it will not be upgradable in the normal way.

It would be better to carry just the user-specific settings (found in your home directory).